# Undo Magic SysRq "remount-ro"

Tags: linux, mount, magic-sysrq

Is there a way to undo an accidental Magic SysRq "remount-ro"? On my notebook keyboard, this combination happens all too often...

I tried to remount the roor partition with `mount -o remount,rw /dev/mapper/kubuntu--vg-root /`, but it fails with

```
mount: /: mount point not mounted or bad option.`
```

`mount` however says:

```
/dev/mapper/kubuntu--vg-root on / type ext4 (ro,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered
```

Comment: It should be mount -o remount, rw /

Comment: Both are possible, according to the man page: `mount -o remount,rw /dev/foo /dir`, but when device and mount point are given, options from fstab are not used.